# How to create strings in for loop with SELECT using variable variables PHP

Tags: php, mysql, string, variables, for-loop

**Where I made a mistake to get output like I wrote below?**

1. Inside array are names of tables.

Let's say in those tables are 0 rows, so everywhere should be 0 as a output.

```
<?php
$g_module =
array(
  'm_b_broadcast_live',
  'm_b_browsing_live',
  'm_e_askfm_likes_live',
  'm_e_facebook_followers_live',
  'm_e_facebook_group_joins_live',
);

for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
  $modules_names = "g_module[$i]";
  $modules_from = '$'.$modules_names;

  $modules_rows = '$g_module_row_'.$i;

  $$modules_rows = mysql_num_rows("SELECT * FROM $$modules_from");
}

echo $g_module_row_1;
echo '</br>';
echo $g_module_row_2;
echo '</br>';
echo $g_module_row_3;
echo '</br>';
echo $g_module_row_4;
echo '</br>';
echo $g_module_row_5;

/* output should be:
0

0

0

0

0
*/
?>
```

Comment: `mysql_num_rows()` takes a result set and not a string with a SQL statement in it.  It's also deprecated, so no longer supported.  You probably need to look into running a basic SQL statement using PDO or mysqli.

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not use the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface which was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Here parameters are **NOT** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and this has severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) in this code. Escape **any** and all user data, especially from `$_POST` or `$_GET`.

Comment: Using variable-variables (e.g. `$$x`) is, at the best of times, *extremely risky*. Using variable-variables in a SQL query is reckless. Don't do it. Just create an array `$g_module_rows` and `push` things into it. Don't create heaps of variables using `$$`.

Comment: A good reason to use arrays is because you can iterate over them. You can't do this easily with piles of variables. Those nine lines of copy-pasted code could boil down to four flexible lines of code that can handle *N* rows with a simple `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments to your question already, `mysql_num_rows()` takes a query result as parameter, not a query string.
*Also, you should use `mysqli`! Look at the documentation [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).*

Something else that you can simplify is to escape the dollar sign so you don't have to concatenate one to `$modules_names` again.

The corrected code would look like this:

```
<?php
$g_module = [
    'm_b_broadcast_live',
    'm_b_browsing_live',
    'm_e_askfm_likes_live',
    'm_e_facebook_followers_live',
    'm_e_facebook_group_joins_live',
];

// you have to create a connection to your database server first
// of course you will have to swap out my placeholders for the actual credentials
$con=mysqli_connect('mysql_server_address_here','username_here','password_here','database_name_here');

for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++){
    $modules_from = "\$g_module[$i]";

    $modules_rows = "\$g_module_row_$i";

    $q=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM $$modules_from");

    //use mysqli_num_rows instead
    $$modules_rows = mysqli_num_rows($q);
}

// close your connection after you are finished
mysqli_close($con);

echo $g_module_row_1;
echo '</br>';
echo $g_module_row_2;
echo '</br>';
echo $g_module_row_3;
echo '</br>';
echo $g_module_row_4;
echo '</br>';
echo $g_module_row_5;
```

Comment: `mysql_query` < `mysqli` < PDO < an ORM.

Comment: Also if you're going to use `mysqli` at least use the object-oriented interface. It's way less verbose and can't accidentally be confused with the `mysql_query` family of functions, saving a lot of time looking for a missing `i`.

Comment: Sorry @tadman, I have til now always used either the procedural mysqli functions or PDO from the start. Because OP used `mysql` I just stuck with that (except for the `i`).
If you want you are always welcome to add another answer that includes PDO or what you think is the best solution.

Comment: Yeah, I'm being a bit particular here, but I see way too many questions where people have barely budged from the crappy old way of `mysql_query` to `mysql_query` with the same flaws present. Using the object-oriented style allows for more of a clean break and avoids a whole myriad of problems, so it's worth promoting. Or PDO, as you say!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $g_module =
    array(
        'm_b_broadcast_live',
        'm_b_browsing_live',
        'm_e_askfm_likes_live',
        'm_e_facebook_followers_live',
        'm_e_facebook_group_joins_live',
    );

    foreach($g_module as $table_name){
        $count = mysql_num_rows("SELECT * FROM $table_name");
        echo "<br/>".$count;
    }
?>
```

I think you should try like this.

Comment: `mysql_num_rows` takes a result, not a string. This code needs a fix.